# Delay and animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I want to animate one object, and after that with delay(5 sec) I want to animate another can somebody told how I can do this. I am pretty new in JS and jQuery.

Comment: what kind of animation?

Comment: @Sampath Liyanage, I want to set height and widht to block, and then return it to started size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `animate` method from **jQuery**:

```
 $("#object1").animate({
   opacity: 0.25,
   height: "toggle"
 }, 5000, function() {
     //On Animation completem animate object 2
     $("#object2").animate({
       opacity: 0.25,
       height: "toggle"
     }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: it works) but I have new problem when I set width all fine, but when height all brokes.

Comment: @excluded_once What do you mean? What error are you getting? try to post your code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First, execute the first animation, and then use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function to execute the second animation (delayed by 5 sec using [setTimeout()](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/)) as soon as the first one has finished executing.

```
$('#element_id').animate({ your_first_animation }, 300).queue(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#element_id').animate({ your_second_animation_after_5sec }, 300) }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Simpler to use 'delay' rather than queue and setTimeout like this:
`$(...).animate({...}).delay(5000).animate({...})`